# I can't get my div to go all the way to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried `float: right`, `right: 0`, `text-align: right`, setting a width, I can't get anything to fix it. The left box is supposed to be in the top left corner and the right box is supposed to be in the top right corner.

```js
function GetClock() {
    var d = new Date();
    var nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate(),
        nyear = d.getFullYear();
    var nhour = d.getHours(),
        nmin = d.getMinutes(),
        nsec = d.getSeconds();
    if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
    if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;
    if (nhour <= 9) {
        nhour = "0" + nhour
    }

    var clockTime = nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec;
    var clockDate = (nmonth + 1) + "/" + ndate + "/" + nyear;
    document.getElementById('clocktime').innerText = clockTime;
    // document.getElementById('clockdate').innerText = clockDate;
}

GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #2b3e50;
    color: #ededed;
}

body {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
}

a {
    color: white
}

.timeBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.tempBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="timeBox">
        <div style="width: 71px;">
            <!--Clock (Time&Date)-->
            <div id="clocktime"></div>
            <script src="clock.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tempBox">
        <div style="width: 71px;">
            <div id="tempBox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's it supposed to look like?

Comment: Have you tried float right ccs attributes ?

Comment: The left most box is supposed to be a clock in the very top left of the screen and the right most box is supposed to be in the very top right of the screen. And yes I have tried float right attribute.

Comment: @GarrettThompson please look to my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for it, and avoid to use position absolute. Try like on my snippet:

```js
function GetClock() {
    var d = new Date();
    var nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate(),
        nyear = d.getFullYear();
    var nhour = d.getHours(),
        nmin = d.getMinutes(),
        nsec = d.getSeconds();
    if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
    if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;
    if (nhour <= 9) {
        nhour = "0" + nhour
    }

    var clockTime = nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec;
    var clockDate = (nmonth + 1) + "/" + ndate + "/" + nyear;
    document.getElementById('clocktime').innerText = clockTime;
    document.getElementById('clockdate').innerText = clockDate;
}

GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    /*color: white;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}


.timeBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.tempBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.tmbxItem{
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    max-width: 146px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="timeBox">
        <div id="clocktime" class="tmbxItem"></div>
        <div id="clockdate" class="tmbxItem"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something called "FlexBox"?
Avoid using float. And right:0 will work only if your parent div has position:relative;.

Suggest giving parent div position:flex, and your child should have justify-content: flex-end; This will automatically push all child divs to right.

For more info:
Here is a quick 100 sec. video on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K74l26pE4YA

Comment: I tried that all but I couldn't get it to work. I probably messed something up somewhere. Probably just need to start over.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because too low reputation but I think you forgot to position your boxes. You use the right and left properties though.

```
.timeBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    left: 0; /* not necessary (can be removed) */
    max-height: 30px;
}

.tempBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0; /* work only on positioned element */
    position: fixed; /* try this */
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` property is ignored in a `flex` container.

The problem is in your code that you declared `flex` in a body 
`float` do not create floating of flex item

Check your problem is solved hope this will help you:

```js
function GetClock() {
    var d = new Date();
    var nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate(),
        nyear = d.getFullYear();
    var nhour = d.getHours(),
        nmin = d.getMinutes(),
        nsec = d.getSeconds();
    if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
    if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;
    if (nhour <= 9) {
        nhour = "0" + nhour
    }

    var clockTime = nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec;
    var clockDate = (nmonth + 1) + "/" + ndate + "/" + nyear;
    document.getElementById('clocktime').innerText = clockTime;
    // document.getElementById('clockdate').innerText = clockDate;
}

GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #2b3e50;
    color: #ededed;
}

body {
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
}

a {
    color: white
}

.timeBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    float:left;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.tempBox {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "seven-seg";
    float: right;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 7.5px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="timeBox">
        <div style="width: 71px;">
            <!--Clock (Time&Date)-->
            <div id="clocktime"></div>
            <script src="clock.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tempBox">
        <div style="width: 71px;">
            <div id="tempBox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```